# How to swap object s1 and s3 in attched StudentTest.java file

Tags: java

### Below is a StudentTest class which uses Student.java to create student

### Student class

```
class Student
 {
    int id;
    static int computeCount;

    int age;
    String name;
    String gender;
    short rank;
    double gpa;
    long phone;
    char degree;

    boolean international;
    double tutionfees=12000;
    double internationalFees=5000;

    Student(int id,String name,String gender,int age,long phone,double gpa, char degree){
      // id=newId;
      // name=newName;
      // gender=newGender;
      // age=newAge;
      // phone=newPhone;
      // gpa=newGpa;
      // degree=newDegree;
      this(id,name,gender, age, phone,gpa,degree,false);    // delegate to second parameterized constructor 
      //international=isInternational;
    }


    // Second parameterized constructor
    Student(int id,String name,String gender,int age,long phone,double gpa, char degree,boolean international){
      this.id=id;
      this.name=name;
      this.gender=gender;
      this.age=age;
      this.phone=phone;
      this.gpa=gpa;
      this.degree=degree;
      this.international=international;
}
```

---

### StudentTest class

```
class StudentTest {
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
        Student s1=new Student(1000,"John","Male",18,2234567890L,3.8,'B');
        Student s2=new Student(1001,"Indresh","Male",20,2234567893L,4.0,'C',true);
        Student s3 = new Student(1002,"Anita","Female",25,2234568793L,4.2,'B',true);
        System.out.println("student1: " + s1.name);
        System.out.println("student2: " + s2.name);
        System.out.println("student3: " + s3.name);

        Student[] students={s1,s2,s3};    // object array of Student type

        // Swap s1 and s3 references

        // Before Swap
        System.out.println("\n\nBefore Swap\n--------");
        System.out.println("student1: " + s1.name);
        System.out.println("student2: " + s2.name);
        System.out.println("student3: " + s3.name);

         // After swap

        swap_s1_n_s3(students,0,2);

        System.out.println("\n\nAfter Swap, Inside StudentTest class\n--------");

        System.out.println("\n\nstudent1: " + s1.name);
        System.out.println("student2: " + s2.name);
        System.out.println("student3: " + s3.name);

   }


static void swap_s1_n_s3(Student[] students,int first,int last)
   {    System.out.println("\n\n------------\nINSIDE SWAP METHOD");
        Student s5;
        s5=students[first];
        students[first]=students[last];
        students[last]=s5;
        
          System.out.println("\n\nstudent1: " + students[0].name);
        System.out.println("student2: " + students[1].name);
        System.out.println("student3: " + students[2].name);
        System.out.println("\nEXIT SWAP METHOD");

   }
 }
```

---

### OUTPUT

$ java StudentTest

student1: Joan
student2: Indresh
student3: Anita

### Before Swap

student1: John
student2: Indresh
student3: Anita

---

INSIDE SWAP METHOD

student1: Anita
student2: Indresh
student3: John

EXIT SWAP METHOD

### After Swap, Inside StudentTest class

student1: John
student2: Indresh
student3: Anita

My question is the swap funtion should also swap the references in main(), but this is not the case, why ?

Comment: Do not use the references `s1`, `s2` and `s3`. Access the array direcrly. The references will continue the same object.

Comment: In the after swap in StudentTest class, you are referencing the students directly by their Student object references and not from the array, hence all output is the same as the before swap output, which was also done directly on the Student objects, only in the swap_s1_n_s3 method do you reference the actual array.

Comment: Your Students[] is swapped but your object s1 isn’t swapped with s3. s1 and s3 still points to respective students only. So your output is right.

Answer (score 2):

The swap-logic works correctly. The problem is of a different nature.

In the code presented, the variables `s1`, `s2` and `s3` are used to hold the initial `Student`-objects, initialize the `students`-array and printed as debugging. No matter, however, what is done to and with `students`, these three variables reference the same `Student`-object that was originally assigned to them. This gets obvious when the variables are declared as `final`.

When printing the `Student`s for debugging, they should be accessed through the `students`-array:

```
System.out.println("student1: " + students[0].name);
System.out.println("student2: " + students[1].name);
System.out.println("student3: " + students[2].name);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Bz5XdE)

Answer (score 1):

Replace main method as below, you will get an idea.

Instead of accessing element by reference you need to access by array[index], you will get exact result what you want.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        Student s1 = new Student(1000, "John", "Male", 18, 2234567890L, 3.8, 'B');
        Student s2 = new Student(1001, "Indresh", "Male", 20, 2234567893L, 4.0, 'C', true);
        Student s3 = new Student(1002, "Anita", "Female", 25, 2234568793L, 4.2, 'B', true);
        System.out.println("student1: " + s1.name);
        System.out.println("student2: " + s2.name);
        System.out.println("student3: " + s3.name);

        Student[] students = {s1, s2, s3};    // object array of Student type

        // Swap s1 and s3 references

        // Before Swap
        System.out.println("\n\nBefore Swap\n--------");
        System.out.println("student1: " + s1.name);
        System.out.println("student2: " + s2.name);
        System.out.println("student3: " + s3.name);

        // After swap

        swap_s1_n_s3(students, 0, 2);

        System.out.println("\n\nAfter Swap, Inside StudentTest class\n--------");

        System.out.println("student1: " + students[0].name);
        System.out.println("student2: " +  students[1].name);
        System.out.println("student3: " +  students[2].name);

    }
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted: It is basically the same answer as mine. So please downvote my answer as well.

Comment: I didn't downvote but the answers are not the same : the other offers and explanation, this one is basically just "use this code". The other is useful to others in the future because it teaches, this answer is useful only to the original asker.